# Draw K5 Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory

In my prac I'm asked to draw the graph K5 but in all my lecture notes I've only covered drawing K with 2 numbers (like K1,2), how does it differ when only a single number is provided?

Answer (score 1):

With only one number, it's not a bipartite graph, but rather a *complete* graph (at least that's what it usually means). For instance, here is $K_4$:

[image]

Comment: Another partly related question. When you have a question with one of the 2 variables of K being 1, how do you graph it? Am I correct in assuming you just connect a single line to all 5 of the other subsets variables?

Comment: If one of the two indices is $1$, you get what is called a _star graph_. Look that up, and you can see why it got that name. To see that it is bipartite, take the center out to the left, and all the "beams" out to the right.